# Creating subclass of NSStackView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, initialization

I try to create a subclass of NSStackView, for example to give it a special color.

To instantiate it, I have to call a superclasses designated init, if I understand right.

How can I detect, which are the designated initializers of NSStackView? Looking at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstackview the only initializer I find is:

```
init(views: [NSView])
```

but the following code doesn't compile with:

> "Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'NSStackView'"

```
class CStackView: NSStackView
{ init(views: [NSView], withColor color: NSColor)
  { super.init(views: views)
    // do something with the color
  }

  required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder)
  { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  } 
}
```

init(coder:) seems to be a designated initializer, but I have want to init the CStackView with its subviews, not having a coder.

Answer (score 3):

`init(views:)` is a convenience initializer.

`NSStackView` doesn't declare any designated initializers, so it inherits them from its superclass, `NSView`, which has `init(frame:)` and `init(coder:)`

You can either have your initializer call `super.init(frame:)` or declare your initializer as a convenience initializer and then it could call `self.init(views:)`.

Comment: If I write my own convenience initializer, I have to call a designated initializer of my own class which then has to call  super.init(frame:) or super.init(coder:). I never have the chance to call NSStackViews init(views:). Is that correct?

Comment: Where do you know from, that init(views:) is a convenience initializer (Except from the complier Error).

Comment: If you write your own convenience initializer then it can call `self.{superclass convenience initializer}` as long as your subclass doesn't also have it's own designated initializer declared.

Comment: You have to click into the function in the docs to see that it's a convenience initializer: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsstackview/1488929-init

Answer (score 0):

With @Dan s help, that´s it.

```
class C3StackView: NSStackView
{ convenience init(views: [NSView], withColor color: NSColor)
  { self.init(views: views)  
    // do something wich the color
  }

  required convenience init?(coder decoder: NSCoder)
  { fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
  } 
}
```